# why below pattern program not giving desired output?

Tags: python

```
n=int(input('enter no of rows\n'))
for row in range(0,n):
    for col in range(0,n):
        if row==0 or col==(n-1):
             print("A",end="")
        else:
            print(end="")
    print()
```

i need output like below .im not getting it .can anyone help me on it , is there any problem with code .

```
AAAAA
 A  A
  A A
   AA
    A
```

Comment: if row==0 or col==(n-1) or col==row:(i've also try by this)

Comment: Could you add a description of what your pattern is supposed to look like? an example for n=5 is not enough to understand what the pattern should be. Also refrain from adding info in comments. Instead use the `edit` button to add it to your question please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your way:

```
n=int(input('enter no of rows\n'))
for row in range(0,n):
    for col in range(0,n):
        if row == 0 or col == (n-1) or row == col:
            print ("A",end ="")
        else:
             print(" ", end ="")
    print()
```

output:

```
enter no of rows
5
AAAAA
 A  A
  A A
   AA
    A
```

Comment: for row in range(n - 2): for this for loop will iterate for row= 0,1,2 right?i didn't  understand how last A  got display in output.

Comment: what you think you will get with 'for row in range(n - 2)' ?

Comment: Smallest change to original code.  Explicit logic, no magic required.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python "feature" and do it with 1 loop:

```
n = int(input('enter no of rows\n'))
print("A" * n)
for row in range(n - 2):
    print(" " * (row + 1) + "A" + " " * (n - row - 3) + "A")
print(" " * (n - 1) + "A")
```

---

*Why does it work?*

First of all, let's take look on result you want to achieve. You want to print in console triangle built with symbols `A`.

To create algorithm with loop we should find something common in each printed line. Let's take a look on output again:

```
0 row:  AAAAA  # no spaces, 5 'A' chars
1 row:   A  A  # 1 space + 'A' + 2 spaces + 'A'
2 row:    A A  # 2 spaces + 'A' + 1 space + 'A'
3 row:     AA  # 3 spaces + 'A' + 0 spaces + 'A'
4 row:      A  # 4 spaces + 'A'
```

I've added some comments to show how I analyze this output. Here we see that **first** and **last** lines dont follow same logic with others. So let's print them outside loop. Now let's try to create algorithm for building "central" rows:

1. Amount of spaces (' ' char) on the start equals `row index`;
2. 'A' char;
3. Amount of spaces between 'A' chars equals `amount of rows` - `row index` - `2` (total length of each row should equal `amount of rows`; we should minus `2`, cause except spaces we print 2 'A' chars);
4. 'A' char.

In python multiplication of string and int creates new string copied amount of times provided in int value. Example: `"A" * 10` will return new string `"AAAAAAAAAA"`. We will use this trick in code.

Now let's code. First of all let's print first line, which contains 'A' symbol repeated `n` times:

```
print("A" * n)
```

Then let's write loop. In my code I've used [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with 1 argument. But we should remember that we've already printed 0 row and should start from 1. In my code it's not so clear, so let's do it in other way:

```
for row in range(1, row - 1):
```

Now let's write code for printing row:

```
print(" " * row              # amount of spaces equals row index
      + "A"                  # 'A' char
      + " " * (n - row - 2)  # amount of spaces between 'A' chars equals
                             # length of row - row index - 2
      + "A")                 # 'A' char
```

And finally print last line:

```
print(" " * (n - 1)          # amount of spaces on the start of last line
                             # equals length of row - 1
      + "A")                 # 'A' char
```

And full code:

```
print("A" * n)
for row in range(1, row - 1):
    print(" " * row              # amount of spaces equals row index
          + "A"                  # 'A' char
          + " " * (n - row - 2)  # amount of spaces between 'A' chars equals 
                                 # length of row - row index - 2
          + "A")                 # 'A' char
print(" " * (n - 1)              # amount of spaces on the start of last line
                                 # equals length of row - 1
      + "A")                     # 'A' char
```

Comment: i just started learning python.i 'm struggling to understand ur code ...i get back to you for any doubts .once again thanks for quick response

Comment: @wiz, I've added detailed explanation, check edits to my answer.

Comment: ,i understood..thnx

Comment: @wiz, choose answer, which helped you.

Comment: the one which u post and the one which u did modifictaion ...both are ok